# SQL Server 2008: How to remove namespace from the elements, but let it display on root

Tags: namespaces, for-xml

I am using SQL Server2008 FOR XML clause to generate XML file using bcp.

When I use the below query, the result is fine:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (        
   'http://base.google.com/ns/1.0' AS g,
   DEFAULT 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'
    )
select ID, Name AS "g:Name" from PaymentMethods For XML PATH ('entry'), Root('feed')
```

Result:

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <entry>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <g:Name>BPay</g:Name>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <g:Name>Cash</g:Name>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

But I also want to add some static elements, say, Title and date after the Root. I am able to do that, but then, the namespace tags appear in the  element as well which I don't want. Please note, I want some elements with the namespace prefix eg,

Query I am using for this is:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (
    'http://base.google.com/ns/1.0' AS g,
    DEFAULT 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'
    )
SELECT 
'Google Feed' As Title,
CONVERT(Date, getdate()) As Updated,
(   
select ID, Name AS "g:Name" from PaymentMethods For XML PATH ('entry'), TYPE
)

FOR XML PATH(''),   Root('feed')
```

And the result I get is:

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <Title>Google Feed</Title>
  <Updated>2012-06-27</Updated>
  <entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
     <ID>1</ID>
    <g:Name>BPay</g:Name>
  </entry>
 <entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <ID>2</ID>
    <g:Name>Cash</g:Name>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

Whereas i want a result like:

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <Title>Google Feed</Title>
  <Updated>2012-06-27</Updated>
  <entry>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <g:Name>BPay</g:Name>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <g:Name>Cash</g:Name>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

Please help...

Thanks,

PS

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use a WITH XMLNAMESPACES clause with correlated queries?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16671926/how-can-i-use-a-with-xmlnamespaces-clause-with-correlated-queries)