# How can I use a WITH XMLNAMESPACES clause with correlated queries?

Tags: sql-server, for-xml

I'm trying to use the `FOR XML` feature of SQL Server to generate some XML, with some specific namespaces.

My target XML should look something like:

```
<ns1:CustomerInvoices xmlns:ns1="urn:example.com:Invoice:01.00">
  <CustomerInvoice>
    <Header>
      <OrderDate>2001-11-13T00:00:00</OrderDate>
      <SalesOrderNumber>SO44643</SalesOrderNumber>
    </Header>
    <Lines>
      <LineTotal>3578.270000</LineTotal>
      <UnitPrice>3578.2700</UnitPrice>
      <OrderQty>1</OrderQty>
    </Lines>
  </CustomerInvoice>
  <CustomerInvoice>...(abbreviated)...</CustomerInvoice>
</ns1:CustomerInvoices>
```

The problem I have, is that when I use the `WITH XMLNAMESPACES` clause, is the namespace declaration appears on lots of the child nodes, which the third party consumer of this XML would "prefer not to get", i.e. I'm doing something like:

```
Use AdventureWorks2008

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('urn:example.com:Invoice:01.00' as ns1)

SELECT      (SELECT     hdr.OrderDate,
                        hdr.SalesOrderNumber
            FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE) AS Header,
            (SELECT     line.LineTotal,
                        line.UnitPrice,
                        line.OrderQty

            FROM        Sales.SalesOrderDetail  AS line

            WHERE       line.SalesOrderID = hdr.SalesOrderID
            FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE) AS Lines

FROM        Sales.SalesOrderHeader  AS hdr

WHERE       hdr.ModifiedDate = '2001-11-20'

FOR XML PATH('CustomerInvoice'), ROOT('ns1:CustomerInvoices')
```

Which gives:

```
<ns1:CustomerInvoices xmlns:ns1="urn:example.com:Invoice:01.00">
  <CustomerInvoice>
    <Header>
      <OrderDate xmlns:ns1="urn:example.com:Invoice:01.00">2001-11-13T00:00:00</OrderDate>
      <SalesOrderNumber xmlns:ns1="urn:example.com:Invoice:01.00">SO44643</SalesOrderNumber>
    </Header>
    <Lines>
      <LineTotal xmlns:ns1="urn:example.com:Invoice:01.00">3578.270000</LineTotal>
      <UnitPrice xmlns:ns1="urn:example.com:Invoice:01.00">3578.2700</UnitPrice>
      <OrderQty xmlns:ns1="urn:example.com:Invoice:01.00">1</OrderQty>
    </Lines>
  </CustomerInvoice>
  <CustomerInvoice>...(abbreviated)...</CustomerInvoice>
</ns1:CustomerInvoices>
```

Is it possible to tweak the query to get the namespaces correct, or will I have to load this into "something else" to remove the redundant namespace declarations?

Comment: May be a repeat : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242070/how-do-i-remove-redundant-namespace-in-nested-query-when-using-for-xml-path

Comment: Also appears to be http://stackoverflow.com/q/11221375/50447

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not alone.

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/265956/suppress-namespace-attributes-in-nested-select-for-xml-statements

I would suggest upvoting that improvement.

There is a work around listed at the connect site above:

http://www.olcot.co.uk/sql-blogs/suppressing-namespace-attributes-in-nested-select-statements-when-using-for-xml-workaround

APPEND/EDIT:

The second link I posted above is now dead.

Here is a different link:

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/rocks/2012/08/28/suppressing-namespace-attributes-in-nested-select-statements-when-using-for-xml-workaround/

The article is named

> Suppressing namespace attributes in nested select statements when
> using FOR XML workaround Arthur-Olcot

if the work-around link(s) "die" in the future.